# Is The Gradle Artifactory Plugin Supposed To Use A Plain Text Or Encrypted Password?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

When I click "Set Me Up" in Artifactory is generates a gradle.properties file something like this:

```
artifactory_user=my_artifactory_user
artifactory_password=WAklvc9LXWDsVcoVILbKyebkQG5uBxos6rIrmi8HjMTB3xicLJbxstmEQwRwIoGN6pBnK3T91I
artifactory_contextUrl=https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory
```

However, when I run `./gradlew artifactoryDeploy` I get this error:

```
> Task :artifactoryDeploy FAILED    
Could not build the build-info object.    
org.jfrog.build.util.VersionException: Error occurred while requesting version information:  Response message: {    
  "errors" : [ {    
    "status" : 401,    
    "message" : "Bad credentials"    
  } ]    
}

...
stacktrace
...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:    
Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.    
> java.io.IOException: Could not publish build-info: Error occurred while requesting version information:  Response message: {    
    "errors" : [ {    
      "status" : 401,    
      "message" : "Bad credentials"    
    } ]    
  }
```

I'm confused because Artifactory is generating this encrypted password but the docs use an example with plain text.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+With+Gradle#WorkingwithGradle-ConfiguringGradle

Is the `artifactory_password` supposed to be encrypted like this or is it supposed to be plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `artifactory_password` parameter can be used for:

- clear text passwords
- encrypted passwords
- API key

If you are getting a Bad credentials error, one of the possible reasons is using an encrypted password when Artifactory is configured with [Password Encryption Policy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+Security+Settings#GeneralSecuritySettings-PasswordEncryptionPolicy) set to Unsupported (not respecting encrypted passwords).
A few things you can do to debug this issue:

- Verify the Password Encryption Policy is set to Supported or Required (requires admin) in Administration -> Security -> Settings
- Test the user and password by trying to call the REST API using a client such a cURL. Make sure you use an API method which requires and authenticated user